# Aggregation based on Date range

Tags: r

I have the following data frame with date and values columns:

```
DF2 <- data.frame("Date"=c("2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-05","2016-09-06"),
              "Value1"=c(20,200,60,150,140),
              "Value2"=c(15,20,15,30,30),
              "Value3"=c(80,42,29,40,39))
```

Then I have two date input parameters:

```
dateFrom <- "2016-09-02"
dateTo <- "2016-09-05"
```

How can I aggregate each numeric column (Value1 - Value3) based on this date range? I'd like to compute simple sum as an aggregation criterium. Many thanks for your advice in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data:

```
DF2 <- data.frame("Date"=as.Date(c("2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-05","2016-09-06"),format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  "Value1"=c(20,200,60,150,140),
                  "Value2"=c(15,20,15,30,30),
                  "Value3"=c(80,42,29,40,39))
dateFrom <- as.Date("2016-09-02",format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dateTo <- as.Date("2016-09-05",format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)    
DF2%>%filter(Date<=dateTo&Date>=dateFrom)%>%select(-Date)%>%colSums()
    Value1 Value2 Value3 
       410     65    111
```

Edit: I change the type for Date (into a Date format) directly in DF2. If  you don't, you have to do:

```
DF2 %>% transform(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))%>%filter(Date<=dateTo&Date>=dateFrom)%>%select(-Date)%>%colSums()
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Your answers are really great!!!! I'm gonna use Haboryme's approach, seems to be best for my purposes.

Comment: Additional question... how can I convert the result into data frame?

Comment: if you store the results in Result, you could do: `data.frame(t(Result),row.names = NULL)`.

Comment: Or you can just add: `%>%t()%>%as.data.frame(row.names=NULL)` to the dplyr call to stay consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It should works.The data should order by Date.

```
DF2 <- data.frame("Date"=as.Date(c("2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-05","2016-09-06")),
              "Value1"=c(20,200,60,150,140),
              "Value2"=c(15,20,15,30,30),
              "Value3"=c(80,42,29,40,39))
dateFrom <- as.Date("2016-09-02")
dateTo <- as.Date("2016-09-05")
start <- which(DF2$Date == dateFrom)
end <- which(DF2$Date == dateTo)
lapply(DF2[start:end,2:4],sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
r <- df[(df$Date >= dateFrom & df$Date <= dateTo),]
data.frame(Date=r$Date, Sum=rowSums(r[-1]))

#        Date Sum
#2 2016-09-02 262
#3 2016-09-03 104
#4 2016-09-05 220
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2016-09-01", "2016-09-02", "2016-09-03", 
"2016-09-05", "2016-09-06"), Value1 = c(20, 200, 60, 150, 140
), Value2 = c(15, 20, 15, 30, 30), Value3 = c(80, 42, 29, 40, 
39)), .Names = c("Date", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (have your Date field as character instead of factor):

```
DF2 <- data.frame("Date"=c("2016-09-01","2016-09-02","2016-09-03","2016-09-05","2016-09-06"),
                  "Value1"=c(20,200,60,150,140),
                  "Value2"=c(15,20,15,30,30),
                  "Value3"=c(80,42,29,40,39), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dateFrom <- "2016-09-02"
dateTo <- "2016-09-05"
apply(subset(DF2, Date >= dateFrom & Date <= dateTo)[2:4], 2, sum)
Value1 Value2 Value3 
   410     65    111
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple `lubdridate` solution:

```
library(lubridate)
interval <- interval(dateFrom, dateTo)

criteria <- ymd(DF2$Date) %within% interval


rowSums(DF2[criteria,2:4])
#  2   3   4 
#262 104 220 

colSums(DF2[criteria,2:4])
# Value1 Value2 Value3 
#    410     65    111
```

I don't know if you want to have the sum of rows (`rowSums`) or columns (`colSums`), you just have to change the last line of code.